# Add Row Context to DAX SWITCH Measure Power BI

Tags: powerbi, switch-statement, dax, measure

The original aim was to create 31 columns, that assess the DAY part of 3 dates and result a specific string in the particular column based on the IF statement. These 31 columns would then sit in a table alongside the title of the event and it would basically be a square Gantt chart for the 31 days.
I could do this code wise in Mcode and advanced editor, but the the performance implications were a non-starter.

I can however build 31 measures that will appear like columns in the Matrix visualization on Power BI, this is fine. Except, Measures do not have a row context naturally.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to add row context, none of the aggregators like SUM, SUMX, MIN, MAX work for a SWITCH statement as I'm not adding anything up, its a Boolean comparison. I understand that normally it'd just be built in a calculated column but its just not suitable.

Basically, I need a way to tie the below SWITCH into the Test_Table, ideally the [Title] column would be used but I just can't see how I can do this.

```
1 = 
    SWITCH(TRUE(),
        // Y-All
        'Test_Table'[Todays_Day_Number] = 1 &&
        'Test_Table'[Baseline_Date_Day_Number] = 1 &&
        'Test_Table'[Forecast_Date_Day_Number] = 1, "Y-All",
        // T-F
        'Test_Table'[Todays_Day_Number] = 1 &&
        'Test_Table'[Baseline_Date_Day_Number] <> 1 &&
        'Test_Table'[Forecast_Date_Day_Number] = 1, "T-F",

        // T-BL
        'Test_Table'[Todays_Day_Number] = 1 &&
        'Test_Table'[Baseline_Date_Day_Number] = 1 &&
        'Test_Table'[Forecast_Date_Day_Number] <> 1, "T-BL",

        // B  
        'Test_Table'[Todays_Day_Number] <> 1 &&
        'Test_Tabler'[Baseline_Date_Day_Number] = 1 &&
        'Test_Table'[Forecast_Date_Day_Number] <> 1, "B",

        // F
        'Test_Table'[Todays_Day_Number] <> 1 &&
        'Test_Table'[Baseline_Date_Day_Number] <> 1 &&
        'Test_Table'[Forecast_Date_Day_Number] = 1, "F",

        // T
        'Test_Table'[Todays_Day_Number] = 1 &&
        'Test_Table'[Baseline_Date_Day_Number] <> 1 &&
        'Test_Table'[Forecast_Date_Day_Number] <> 1, "T",
        "N"
)
```

As columns, this was multiples of conditions, 31 times for every row in the table, even filtered down it just did not help.

I'm probably missing something obvious, I know Gantt charts are available, but that's not the remit from the client.

Error is as follows:

A single value for column 'Todays_Day_Number' in table "Test_Table" cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

Calculated column for each day using If, then, else, and, each
Reduced processed rows
MAX
MIN
SUMX
SUM
ALL
SELECTEDVALUE
COUNTROWS
list goes on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`SELECTEDVALUE(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function).

Don't create 31 measures, instead create one measure and use a table for the columns. For example, create a Calculated Table with:

```
Dim Day = 
  SELECTCOLUMNS(
    GENERATESERIES(1, 31),
    "Day", [Value]
  )
```

Use this new table/column for your Matrix Columns. Then have just this one Measure for the Matrix Values:

```
Day Measure =
  var colDay = SELECTEDVALUE('Dim Day'[Day], -1) // -1 for when not in scope
  var dayT = SELECTEDVALUE('Test_Table'[Todays_Day_Number])
  var dayB = SELECTEDVALUE('Test_Table'[Baseline_Date_Day_Number])
  var dayF = SELECTEDVALUE('Test_Table'[Forecast_Date_Day_Number])

  return SWITCH( TRUE(),
    // Y-All
    dayT = colDay && 
    dayB = colDay && 
    dayF = colDay, "Y-All",
    
    // T-F
    dayT = colDay && 
    dayB <> colDay && 
    dayF = colDay, "T-F",
    
    // T-BL
    dayT = colDay && 
    dayB = colDay && 
    dayF <> colDay, "T-BL",
    
    // B
    dayT <> colDay && 
    dayB = colDay && 
    dayF <> colDay, "B",
    
    // F
    dayT <> colDay && 
    dayB <> colDay && 
    dayF = colDay, "F",
    
    // T
    dayT = colDay && 
    dayB <> colDay && 
    dayF <> colDay, "T"
  )
```

Comment: Sam Niser, thank you very much, worked like a charm.
I need to learn how you built this, I'm not sure how its providing the row context so there is still huge gaps in my knowledge, but you are awesome, thank you.